# Image of a complete lattice by a complete lattice homomorphism

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

It is easy to show that if $\varphi: L \to M$ is a complete lattice homomorphism, then $\varphi(L)$ is a complete sublattice of $M$. It follows that, under the same assumption, if $L'$ is a complete sublattice of $L$, then $\varphi(L')$ is a complete sublattice of $M$ (and of $\varphi(L)$).

We also know that a subset $L'\subseteq L$ can be a complete lattice under the order relation of $L$ without being a complete sublattice of $L$.

**Question**: does the following assertion hold?
If $\varphi: L \to M$ is a complete lattice homomorphism,
if $L' \subseteq L$ is a complete lattice, then $\varphi(L')$ is a complete lattice.

Comment: Can you spell out the second paragraph? Specifically, what do you mean by '*included in $L$*'? Included by an embedding of lattices/posets?

Comment: By "$L'$ is included in $L$" I mean that $L'$ is included in $L$ if we see $L'$ and $L$ as sets.

Comment: A set is not a lattice, I guess you mean posets. Can you give an example?

Comment: Let me rephrase: If $(L,\leq)$ is a complete lattice, and if $L'$ is a subset of $L$, then let $\preceq$ be the restriction of $\leq$ to $L'\times L'$. Then $(L',\preceq)$ can be a complete lattice without $L'$ being a complete sublattice of $(L,\leq)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false; indeed, $\varphi(L')$ may not even be a lattice.  For instance, let $L$ be the free Boolean algebra on four elements $a,b,c,d$, and let $M$ be a finite Boolean algebra with four distinct elements $x,y,z,w$ such that $x,y\leq z,w$ but they are otherwise incomparable.  Let $\varphi:L\to M$ be the unique Boolean homomorphism that maps $a,b,c,d$ to $x,y,z,w$.  It is a complete homomorphism since $L$ and $M$ are finite.

Now let $L'=\{0,a,b,c,d,1\}\subset L$, which is a complete lattice since $a,b,c,d$ are incomparable.  Then $\varphi(L')=\{0,x,y,z,w,1\}$, which is not a lattice since $x$ and $y$ have no join.